# Describe the rank of the matrix as a function of $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \alpha \\ 1 & \alpha & 1 \\ \alpha & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Describe the rank of this matrix as a function of $\alpha$.

To my knowledge the rank is the dimension of the column space of matrix if my knowledge serves me justly.  So I must embark on row reduction of this matrix to obtain rank.

Through some challenging computation I obtain the following result:

$$(2-\alpha -\alpha^2)\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

So I see the rank is $3$ since there are three independent vectors in column space of matrix.  But I don't know how to make the function.

$2-\alpha-\alpha^2 = (2-\alpha)(1+\alpha)$

Can I say when $\alpha = -2, 1$ then $Rank = 0$ and $Rank = 3$ else?

Comment: A function can be defined "piecewise" in that way.  Typically a large left brace is used to group the statements that define the function.

Answer (score 0):

Row reduction:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&\alpha\\
1&\alpha&1\\
\alpha&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-R_1,\,R_3-\alpha R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&\alpha\\
0&\alpha-1&1-\alpha\\
0&1-\alpha&1-\alpha^2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3+R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&\alpha\\
0&\alpha-1&1-\alpha\\
0&0&2-\alpha-\alpha^2\end{pmatrix}$$

We have then that if $\;\alpha^2+\alpha-2=(\alpha+2)(\alpha-1)\neq0\;$,  the rank is $\;3\;$ , thus:

$$\begin{cases}\alpha\neq-2,\,1\implies\;&\text{rank}\,=3\\{}\\
\alpha=2\implies &\text{rank}\,=2\\{}\\
\alpha=1\implies&\text{rank}\,=1\end{cases}$$

I think the above is way simpler, no need to reduce all the way to canonic form the matrix.